# nothing will output

Tags: java, arrays, printing, for-loop, output

no matter where I place the output statement, whether is it for 1 place of the array, all of the array, or even the count variable. I can't print out ANYTHING to the console. I have tried printing in the main, and in the functions. any ideas?

**Edit1: I have discovered I can print inside a jswing window, but still no luck to the console, which is making error checking difficult.**

**Given the fact that I can still output correctly in a window, and people claim eclipse will print it out, I have deemed that the console for my ancient text editor is just incompetent, I appreciate the help**
'

```
//=========================//
//colby moniz project 9-1  //
//Number sorter            //
//=========================//

//===========================================//
//This program takes 10 integers and sorts   //
//them into even, odd, and negative.         //
//===========================================//

//=============//
//Import Files //
//=============//
import javax.swing.*;       // DRAW DIALOG BOX CLASS
import java.awt.*;          // IMPORT AWT TO CHANGE FONT AND COLORS




public class p91 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {


        //=================================//
        //varbiles section                 //
        //=================================//
        sorter sort = new sorter();   //Creatests an instances of sorter, inside main.
        int[] test = new int[10];
        int inputNum;

        //================================//
        //Introduction windows            //
        //================================//    
        info( "This program will sort 10 intergers, \n into the catagories minimum, maximum and negitive",
        "Introduction" );
        //===========================//
        //fill up array              //
        //===========================//
        for(int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
        {
            inputNum = input("please input number " + (count + 1), "Input");
            test[count] = inputNum;
        }   




        for(int count = 0; count < 10; count++)
        {
          System.out.print(test[count]);    
        }


    }





//====================================================//
//Functions                                           //
//====================================================//    


        public static void info(String a, String b)
    {
           //================================//
           //Introduction window             //
           //================================//
            int close = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                a, b,                                      
                                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE); 

            checkCloseInt(close); 
    }

        public static void checkCloseInt(int close)
    {
            //=====================================
            //checks to see if user closed program 
            //=====================================                 
            if ((close == JOptionPane.CLOSED_OPTION) || 
                (close == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION)  ||
                 (close == JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION))          
                 System.exit(0);       
    }

        public static int input(String a, String b)
    {
           //================================//
           //input                           //
           //================================//
            boolean parsable;
            int inputParse = 999;
            String input;

           do
           {           
                     input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,
                                        a, b,                                      
                                       JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE); 

                    //======================//
                    //Check if close        //
                    //======================//
                        if(input == null)
                        {
                            System.exit(0);
                        }

                    parsable = error(input);

           }
           while(parsable == false);

        inputParse = Integer.parseInt(input);  
                    System.out.print(inputParse); 
        return inputParse; 
    }



    public static boolean error(String input)
    {
         //======================
         //Check if parsable
         //=======================
         boolean parsable = true;
          try
          { 
            int inputParse = Integer.parseInt(input);
          }
          catch(NumberFormatException e)
          {
           parsable = false;
          } 

          if(parsable == false)
          {
                    errorWindow("Please input a number");
          } 

          return parsable; 



    }

        public static void errorWindow(String a)
    {
           //================================//
           //Introduction window             //
           //================================//
            int close = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                                a, "Error",                                    
                                JOptionPane.DEFAULT_OPTION, 
                                JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE); 

            checkCloseInt(close); 
    }




}
```

'

Comment: I executed your code in Eclipse. After entering the 10 numbers I checked the console and there they were! 10 numbers as previously entered! Not to mention also the result of executing the `System.out.print(inputParse)` ...

You need to provide more details...

Comment: [Here](http://www.jcreator.com/forums/index.php?showtopic=1620)

Answer (score 0):

Use `System.out.println();` this works for me´.

Comment: `Log.e(String, String)` is applicable only in android not a simple java app

Comment: I tried println, nothing happened. If it helps, after each input window it flickers before moving onto the next.